# ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE value stored in Varchar can't get hex value SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, encryption, sql-server-2008-r2

I"m using SQLServer 2008 R2

There is a table that contains a varchar field. we have some third party software that writes to our database. we have no control over how it writes to it. we need some data to be encrypted in order for the tool to encrypt data it has to write to a varchar or similar text field. After talking with the Vendor we figured out they are setting the field doing something like this

```
update <table>
Set <varchar_field> = ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(N'<passphrase>', '<clear_text>')
Where <some_condition>
```

ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE returns a VarBinary value. So a varbinary value is set into a varchar field. When I look in the database it appears as if the field is blank but if I run.

```
SELECT
Cast(DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(N'<passphrase>', <varchar_field>)  AS NVARCHAR)
From <table>
```

I get back the original value.

my problem is that I want to know what the encrypted value looks like in hex form. I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

I tried

```
Cast(<varchar_field> as varchar)
```

and

```
Convert(varchar, <varchar_field>)
```

they both come back with the empty looking value that actually contains something.
I want to see something like 0x0103939FFA0293. The hex that is the binary that is the encrypted value stored in a varchar field.

**Update Answer**

what I had tried was

```
Convert(varchar, <varchar_field>)
```

thinking that I needed to convert the real binary value into a varchar, but what I needed to do was convert the varchar to varbinary. Converting to varbinary seems to have gotten me what I need.

```
Convert(varbinary, <varchar_field>)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. [***ALWAYS, ALWAYS, ALWAYS*** define variable-length data types ***WITH AN EXPLICIT LENGTH***](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).
2. Why are you mixing `VARCHAR` and `NVARCHAR`?
3. To see the binary value as a string, you need to use style 1:

   ```
    DECLARE @y VARBINARY(8000);

    SELECT @y = ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(N'hello there', N'secret');

    SELECT AsBinary = @y, AsString = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4000), @y, 1);
   ```

Comment: if you are talking about this the cast to NVARCHAR I don't know what the 3rd part tool is doing but if I Cast to VARCHAR I get Some wierd Kanji sytle characters if I cast to NVARCHAR I get the original value back. I think it has to do with the Decrypt function more then what is stored in the field. but I actually had to convert to VARBINARY not VARCHAR

Comment: Interestingly, when I do this it is the opposite: nvarchar puts out some Chinese/Asian hieroglyphs while varchar does my English text.